# How to order by in mySQL without the punctuation signs

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, collation

Consider the following spanish strings from a database table column:

```
¿Donde estas?
!Aqui ando¡
Porque
...Donde
¿Porque?
```

If I use the different Spanish collations offer by mySQL to sort the table column, the punctuation signs will be included in the sorting. Some spanish collations will order the strings with the punctuation at the beginning, some at the end.

But, according to the Spanish Academy of Letters, the sorting only applies to the official Spanish alphabet (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j ,k, l ,m, n, ñ, o, p, q, r, s, t, u ,v ,w ,x, y, z), therefore the punctuation signs should never be use to order a string. 
The order use by all mySQL Spanish collations are wrong and i don’t want to use them.

According to Spanish Academy of Letters, the correct sorting order for the strings above is:

```
!Aqui ando¡
¿Donde estas?
Donde estas
...Donde
Porque
¿Porque?
```

So, what are my next best options...

Can I use regexp in my query to order without the puntuaction signs?

Or, I have no choice to create a column, let's call it sort_name, that contains the string without the punctuation signs, and use that column to order by? Is this the best approach?

Keep in mind that I will still need to use the Spanish collation in mySQL to order the character ñ, a character that goes in between the n and o.

Comment: kept researching and there seems to be no regexp function (like oracle´s regexp_replace) to order by in mysql... too bad.. So my other options is a new column or something else

Answer (score 1):

In Spanish, at most the first character is punctuation or there's a `...`.  You could do something like:

```
order by (case when left(col, 3) = '...' then substr(col, 4)
               when left(col, 1) in ('!', '?', . . .) then substr(col, 2)
               else col
          end)
```

(My apologies, but I don't have the appropriate Spanish characters on my keyboard for the `in` list.)

Comment: this means that i have to case all possible puntuaction signs and accented characters and other stuff. What if the string starts with two punctuattion signs. Between adding a new column and using casing, im not sure...

Comment: i´m analyzing my data and found this case: Ole con ole and ¡Ole, catapum! If i use the casing solution, ¡Ole, catapum! will sort after Ole con ole, and that's wrong. In other words, special punctuation characters can also be found inside the string not just at the beggining. The more i think about it, the more i believe adding a new column is the solution...

Comment: @Marco . . . You may not need to add a new column.  You can just put the logic in the `order by` clause.  By the way, have you set the locale to "es_ES"?

Comment: where do i set the locale es_ES?

Comment: right now, im testing REGEXP inside a case inside an order by... not sure if it's going to work

Comment: another solution is to get the result set as is and create a function in PHP to do the order... that i like better then the one column

Comment: just finished 7 hours of testing and, if it helps, decide it to use the extra column solution. The reason: i'm dealing with audio recording titles and in a lot of titles, there is not a common logic and too many exceptions. I've seen titles that start with weird characters, etc... There's really no case in trying to do a casing for all of those cases... it's too complicated and very spaghetti. Instead, i will use a transliteration column (sort_name) and insert a clean name for sorting, ordering, selecting the first unaccented character, etc. I hope i made the right decision.

Answer (score 1):

One option may be to try to use a UDF [Regular Expression MySQL UDFs](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp), specifically REGEXP_REPLACE?.

Another option may be to use [common_schema](https://code.google.com/p/common-schema/), specifically [replace_all](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/replace_all.html) function, something like:

```
SELECT `mycolumn` FROM `mytable` ORDER BY `common_schema`.replace_all(`mycolumn`, '¡!¿?.', '');
```

You would have to work out some details, but are possible options.